# Has there been known of a board game that co exists with a GM?

Tags: recommendations

I was curious to know if there was a RPG themed boardgame (or a RPG in a box) 
that could **use GM's as a primary mechanic**, or just in there.
Kinda like to GM as much as I like to play a board game doing both would be amazing, even if what you narrate is decided by dice or cards.

Would you know of any titles by any chance?

(the reason for mice and mystics is that its commonly known as a **RPG in a box)**

Answer (score 5):

I think games like Descent is what you're looking for. It's a boardgame where a GM plays against a group of adventurers, and you can add as much roleplay as the group sees fit. 
If Star Wars is your thing, Imperial Assault is basically Descent re-themed.

Comment: "Mansions of Madness" also falls under this category. When compared to Descent, Mansions have flawed mechanics but a more immersive narrative.
I would say that Descent is a light version Dungeons&Dragons and Mansions are a light version of Call of Cthulhu.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.

A game like HeroQuest can be seen as RPG Light with limited rules. (And you could use the props with other RPG's).

A game like Aye Dark Overlord doesn't have a GM, but there is one player (the dark overlord) that needs to be pleased by the other players. So there is a bit of a narrator.